# Update list when item in data changes in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an Activities class that adopts `ObservableObject` protocol and has an `items` array property that stores Activity objects that also adopt `ObservableObject`.

```
class Activity: ObservableObject, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var title: String
    @Published var description: String
    @Published var numberOfTimesCompleted: Int = 0

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encode(description, forKey: .description)
        try container.encode(numberOfTimesCompleted, forKey: .numberOfTimesCompleted)
    }

    init(title: String, description: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        numberOfTimesCompleted = 0
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
        numberOfTimesCompleted = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .numberOfTimesCompleted)
    }
}

class Activities: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Activity] {
        didSet {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(items) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "items")
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        if let items = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "items") {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let decoded = try? decoder.decode([Activity].self, from: items) {
                self.items = decoded
                return
            }
        }

        self.items = []
    }
}
```

I am using a `List` to display my array dynamically like so

```
List {
  ForEach(activities.items) { activity in
    NavigationLink(destination: ActivityView(activity: activity)) {
      HStack {
        Text("\(activity.numberOfTimesCompleted)")
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text(activity.title)
          Text(activity.description)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I pass an Activity to a different view (in the NavigationLink) and edit the `numberOfTimesCompleted` property, the change is not reflected when I navigate back to the list.  If I add a new Activity instance to the list, the list updates and the new `numberOfTimesCompleted` value is reflected in the Activity I edited before. I have a feeling I am close, but I am just learning Swift and ObservableObject and therefore am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the list view has an array of activities: `var items: [Activity]` and the child has a single `Activity` from that array.  You have made the activity `Identifiable` and that id is constant, so what happens is you pass the activity in from the array and you modify it, but as far as the array is concerned, nothing has changed: all of the objects in the array have exactly the same id, so its not going to reload anything.  You need to trigger a reload of the activity.  you may want to consider using an environment object or passing a change closure down that actually performs the mutation on the array so that the list view rebuilds.  It will only rebuild itself if it can detect that the published array is different from the last value.

Comment: I am open to changing the structure of my data/classes. Is there is a "best practice"  (or at least better than how I am doing it) method of sending an item to a detail view and editing it? I think I grasp the idea of sending a change closure down, but I am having a hard time imagining what it looks like in Swift and how well it would scale if I wanted to be able to edit multiple properties on the instance of Activity (would I have to send in a closure for every property I wanted to edit or try to make a generic closure method?)

Comment: I ran into this problem when using a Codable as the basis for my list, and the field I was using as an identifier never changed. I added this field to the codable to generate a unique id each time, and used it as the identifier instead, and it works well: let identifier = UUID()